# Java timeout since last received datagram

Tags: java, multithreading, udp, server

I have the following code in my main application:

```
package acast;

import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;

public class ACast {

    private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String> queue;

    public ACast() throws SocketException{
        queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String>();
        UDPServer srv = new UDPServer(4321);
        srv.addUDPacketListener(new UDPPacketListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPacketReceived(String packet) {
                ACast.this.queue.offer(packet);
            }
        });
        srv.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SocketException {
        try{
            new ACast();   
        }
        catch(SocketException e){
            //e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Socket allready opened. Can't start application");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

}
```

My UDPServer extends Thread and calls onPacketReceived every time it receives an UDP datagram. I want my main app to do something every time a configured timeout passes since the last received datagram. I would like to avoid running a Thread that just checks the timeout from second to second. I would like to start a countdown thread exactly on the moment of the last received datagram and cancel any other ongoing timeout threads if available. Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to start a [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) with the timeout task, and every time a new datagram is received, cancel the currently running timer and start a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I would lose the asynchronicity altogether, and use blocking I/O with a read timeout.